# Converting ToUniversalTime in the DST day

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

I try to verify if some machines are synchronized. For that I read the hrSystemTime OID of a remote machine in a string, convert it to DateTime and compare it with the time of the local machine. I do this once a day at 1:50 AM. In November 3rd, at 1:50 AM, diff showed an hour difference, while diff2 showed no difference. This 1 hour diff pop up if I verify only on this day between 1:00 AM and 2:00 AM. (2:00 AM is the time when DST is changing the hour to 1:00 AM for winter).

```cs
DateTime localTime;
DateTime remoteTime;
TimeSpan diff, diff2;
localTime = DateTime.Now;
remoteTime = Convert.ToDateTime("11/03/2013 1:50:00 AM");
diff = localTime.ToUniversalTime() - remoteTime.ToUniversalTime();
diff2 = localTime.ToLongTimeString() - remoteTime.ToLongTimeString();
```

These are the printed values:

```cs
localTime.ToUniversalTime() = 11/03/2013 1:50:00 AM
remoteTime.ToUniversalTime() = 11/03/2013 1:50:00 AM
localTime.ToLongTimeString() = 11/02/2013 8:50:00 PM
remoteTime.ToLongTimeString() = 11/02/2013 9:50:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just use `DateTime.UtcNow` on both systems and compare those.  That eliminates issues of local time zones and DST affecting the comparison.

You should probably also use an ISO8601 formatted string when comparing between two systems, in case those systems have different date formats due to regional settings.  You can get that with `yourDateTime.ToString("o")`.

But also consider, you are probably not taking into account network transmittal delay time in your comparison.  For that, you should use NTP rather than writing your own code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you run this every day at 1:50 AM, do you read dateTime.Now(). 
It looks like your DateTime.Now has changed from or to DST correctly, resulting in a different Universal time, but you are, in Universal time, running the job at a different time by the looks of it.

If you make sure you retrieve the local and remote time including the time zone information, it will include a DST-aware UTC-offset so that even when one side switches DST it should not affect your comparison.

Do be aware that the clock that governs your job scheduling should be aware of a DST change.